# Netbeans Platform Progress bar

Tags: java, netbeans, progress-bar

I want to show the progress of the two [thread](/questions/tagged/thread). It works wonderful with one, but when I am trying to add another one, something is going wrong.

I'm trying:

```
ProgressHandle ph = ProgressHandleFactory.createHandle("MyTask1");
ph.start();
ph.finish();
ProgressHandle ph2 = ProgressHandleFactory.createHandle("MyTask2");
ph2.start();
ph2.finish();
```

What I need to do is to show progress of 2 executing tasks like in  [netbeans](/questions/tagged/netbeans) IDE.

Answer (score 0):

You should execute your code in a `Runnable` thread. e.g.:

```
RequestProcessor RP = new RequestProcessor("my RP"); 
final ProgressHandle ph = ProgressHandleFactory.createHandle("my task 1"); 
task = RP.create(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int workunits = 100;
                ph.start(workunits);
                for(int i = 0; i < workunits; i++){
                   //do some work
                   ph.progress(i);
                }
                ph.finish();
            }
        });
task.schedule(0);
```

adding more tasks via `RP` is easy, you can use also `RP.post(runnable)`